# Problema com INSERT INTO

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, inserir

Estou tentando fazer um `INSERT` no `MS SQL`, ao rodar o código, não ocorre nenhum erro, porem não faz o `INSERT` no sql, ao rodar um script manualmente no sql o mesmo grava sem nenhum problema.

Já tentei das duas formas, a que está comentada também.

```
        private void InsertToDatabase(string Name, string Document, string Board, int Block, int apartment, string AuthorizedFrom, string DataEntry, string Comments)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(DBOConnect.connectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO visitors (name, document, board, block, apartment, authorized_from, date_entry, username, comments) VALUES ('" + Name + "', '" + Document + "', '" + Board + "', '" + Block + "', '" + apartment + "', '" + AuthorizedFrom + "', '" + DataEntry + "', '" + Profile.LoginInformation[0].Username + "', '" + Comments + "')", connect);
            connect.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connect.Close();

            //using (SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(DBOConnect.connectionString))
            //using (SqlCommand cmd = connect.CreateCommand())
            //{
            //    cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO visitors (name, document, board, block, apartment, authorized_from, date_entry, username, comments) VALUES (@Name, @Document, @Board, @Block, @apartment, @AuthorizedFrom, @DataEntry, @Username, @Comments)";
            //    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Name);
            //    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Document", Document);
            //    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Board", Board);
            //    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Block", Block);
            //    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@apartment", apartment);
            //    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AuthorizedFrom", AuthorizedFrom);
            //    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DataEntry", DataEntry);
            //    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Profile.LoginInformation[0].Username);
            //    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comments", Comments);
            //    connect.Open();
            //    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            //    connect.Close();
            //}
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            System.Media.SystemSounds.Exclamation.Play();
            var frmMain = System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows.OfType<MainWindow>().FirstOrDefault();
            frmMain.ShowMessageAsync("Erro", ex.Message);

            baseGrid.Children.Remove(psbState);
            btnSave.IsEnabled = true;
        }

        System.Media.SystemSounds.Asterisk.Play();

        baseGrid.Children.Remove(psbState);
        baseGrid.Children.Add(lbState);

        ClearContent();
    }
```

Estrutura da tabela:

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[visitors] (
    [Id]              INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [name]            VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [document]        VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
    [board]           VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
    [block]           INT           NULL,
    [apartment]       INT           NULL,
    [authorized_from] VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [date_entry]      DATETIME      NULL,
    [username]        VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
    [comments]        VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Encontrei onde está o erro, porem não sei como corrigi-lo, erro:

Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Invalid object name 'visitors'.

String Connection:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="dbConn" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
    connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Data\data.mdf;Integrated Security=True"/>
```

Comment: Algum erro em especifico?

Comment: Na  segunda forma, você precisa especificar o CommandType, que pode ser StoredProcedure ou Text.

Comment: E já confirmou qual o schema a que a tabela pertence? Experimente colocar o schema no select que está a fazer.

Answer (score 1):

A variavel apartment e block sao inteiros logo nao utilize as '' neles.

Comment: Acho que o erro pode ser isso sim. Mais temos que saber qual tipo é a coluna no banco.

Comment: Uma pergunta: Debugando a instrução o que está sendo passado para o banco? Você já fez isso? Pega o que está sendo passado e poste, pode ser que esteja dando tilt. Cai no catch? Se sim qual exception? Passe essas coisas para termos subsídio.

Comment: Não cai no Catch, vai normal porem não faz o insert

Comment: Debugando, os parâmetros são:

  _commandText "INSERT INTO visitors (name, document, board, block, apartment, authorized_from, date_entry, username, comments) VALUES ('Test', '111111', 'AAA1111', '1', '34', 'Morador Teste - Cônjuge', '2015-07-21 23:04:06', 'Admin', '')" string

Comment: Bom ta tudo ali, Editei o Post, agradeço se puderem ajudar.

Comment: Sim la esta. os numeros nao utilizam ''. A nao ser que sejam strings na base de dados.

Answer (score 0):

Creio que o problema esteja no schema padrão do seu usuário que não é o dbo. Para verificar se é isso, apenas coloque [dbo].[visitors] no INSERT INTO e veja o resultado. Se funcionar como esperado, você pode deixar o schema do usuário como padrão [dbo]. Segue um link de referência https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282665/possible-to-set-default-schema-from-connection-string. Lembre-se que o seu usuário é a conta do Windows que está rodando a aplicação pois você está utilizando o na connection string o parâmetro Integrated Security=True.

Answer (score 0):

um exemplo de persistência usando SqlClient

```
public class Conexao
    {
        //declarar atributos..
        //protected -> somente pode ser acessado por herança
        protected SqlConnection Con;    //conexão com o banco de dados
        protected SqlCommand Cmd;       //executar comandos SQL
        protected SqlDataReader Dr;     //Ler dados de consultas 
        protected SqlTransaction Tr;    //Transações em banco de dados (commit/rollback)

        //declarar os metodos..
        protected void OpenConnection() //conexão...
        {
            Con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["aula"].ConnectionString);
            Con.Open(); //conexão aberta!
        }

        protected void CloseConnection() //desconectar...
        {
            Con.Close(); //conexão fechada!
        }
    }



public class ClienteDal : Conexao
 {

    public void Insert(Cliente c)
            {
                try
                {
                    OpenConnection(); //abrir conexão..
                    Cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Cliente(Nome, Email, Sexo, DataCadastro) values(@v1, @v2, @v3, GetDate())", Con);
                    Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@v1", c.Nome);
                    Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@v2", c.Email);
                    Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@v3", c.Sexo.ToString());
                    Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); //executar..
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    //lançar uma exceção para o projeto principal..
                    throw new Exception("Erro ao inserir Cliente: " + e.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    CloseConnection(); //fechar conexão..
                }
            }
}
```